# How to run a query in model and load in the controller?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I was doing a query in the controller but it came to my attention that I should do it in the model.

This is the code I have in the controller

```
    $this->db->where('page', 'your-secret-skill');
    $this->data['articles'] = $this->article_m->get();
```

and this is the get method I have in the core model:

```
    public function get($id = NULL, $single = FALSE){

    if ($id != NULL) {
        $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
        $id = $filter($id);
        $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
        $method = 'row';
    }
    elseif($single == TRUE) {
        $method = 'row';
    }
    else {
        $method = 'result';
    }

    if (!count($this->db->ar_orderby)) {
        $this->db->order_by($this->_order_by);
    }
    return $this->db->get($this->_table_name)->$method();
}
```

How would I go about this and do the query in the articles model and loading it with the controller?

Comment: Lol, what about reading the first lines of CI documentation

Comment: I've been on it but nothing worked for me so far

Answer (score 1):

You should inherit the CI_Model with the Articles model and in it you can write your query as:

```
class Articles_m extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
          parent::__construct();
          $this->table_name = 'articles';
     }


    public function get()
    {
     $this->db->where('page', 'your-secret-skill');
     $query = $this->db->get($this->table_name);
     return $query->result();
    }

}
```

and then in your controller:

```
$this->data['articles'] = $this->article_m->get();
```

Comment: I get a server error, and the log/ in the CI file doesn't give me pointers what is happening :\

Comment: Nevermind, I had a syntax error (like 99% of the times lol) it works now

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from the controller first:

```
$this->db->where('page', 'your-secret-skill');
```

Instead send `your-secret-skill` as a parameter to your model function:

```
$where = array( 'page', 'your-secret-skill' );
$this->data['articles'] = $this->article_m->get('','',$where);
```

In your model:

```
public function get($id = NULL, $single = FALSE, $where = array){
    if(isset($where) && is_array($where)){
        $this->db->where($where);
    }
}
```